# Val3: Reading an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: robotic-arm, industrial-robot

I want to create a pPoint in Val3, which creates an array with the coordinates. The coordinates to be approached are in an Excel table. Is it possible to read this table using a command with Val3 and import it into the pPoint array?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of possibilities. If you are using Staubli Robotics Studio (SRS). you could create the point variable or array and do a copy paste operation.

The other possibility is to save the excel spreadsheet as a Comma Separated Value file (CSV). Then install the "expansion" software add on for the SRC version installed on your controller. The expansion add on has "beta" instruction that are being tested for possible use in future releases of SRC (Staubli robotics control). The expansion add on has instruction for opening, reading, and close files. It will be possible to easily parse the CSV file and copy the data into the fields of a point variable.

The software add on such as "expansion" are versions specific. New versions have to be complied each time SRC is updated. The Software add ons are not publicly available and you will have to contact the Staubli Technical Support team for your area to get a copy.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
The copy and paste variant is currently my interim solution and will not be a good solution to my problem in the foreseeable future. I will then contact Stäubli to get the expansion add on. Thank you for pointing this out and have a nice day.